# Multiple combined ifs inside an if

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got multiple combined `if`s inside another `if`. If there is only one `if` with combined conditions, it works fine. As soon as i add another, it stops working. The js code looks like this

```
var ttl = //dynamic text
var curcookie = //dynamicly calculated number
if ( ttl.indexOf('something') !== -1 )
//this "if" works in any case
      {
         var result1 = "dynamic number" //works fine as well
         var result2 = "dynamic number" //works fine as well
         var result3 = "dynamic number" //works fine as well

        if ( ( curcookie > result1) && (curcookie < result2) ) { $(".div1").show(); }
        //works without this one bellow
        if ( ( curcookie > result2) && (curcookie < result3) ) { $(".div2").show(); }
        // works without one above
        if (curcookie > result3) { $(".div3").show(); }     
      }
}
```

as i've already mentioned, it all works fine until i add

```
if ( ( curcookie > result2) && (curcookie < result3) ) { $(".div2").show();}
```

so, I'm guessing my mistake is somewhere here, but I have no idea what exactly it is.

fiddles

working
https://jsfiddle.net/qxhm2vx9/

not working
https://jsfiddle.net/rbhz7Lfj/

Comment: What does "it stops working" mean? What's the error?

Comment: What is the intent of the code? Can you describe the purpose in more detail? "It works fine until..." isn't helpful if we can't understand how you want it to behave. Can you provide actual values for `ttl`, `curcookie`, `result1`, `result2`, and `result3`?

Comment: It looks like it's supposed to show one of the 3 divs depending on where the cookie value is in relation to `result1`, `result2`, and `result3`.

Comment: Make sure that `result1` is lower than `result2`, and `result2` is lower than `result3`.

Comment: Also, none of the DIVs will be shown if `curcookie` is exactly equal to any of the `resultX` variables. You should probably change `<` to `<=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an opening bracket here

```
if ( curcookie > result2) && (curcookie < result3) ) { $(".div2").show(); }
```

should be

```
if (( curcookie > result2) && (curcookie < result3) ) { $(".div2").show(); }
```

well thats why the jsfiddle isnt working

Answer (score 0):

If the expected output of your code is to show all div classes (`.div1`, `.div2`, `.div3`), you need to be sure that all of your conditions will be *true*.

If class `.div2` is not displaying, its possible *false* on its condition.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an opening bracket in your `if` statement.

This:

```
if (curcookie > result2) && (curcookie < result3)) {
    $(".div2").show();
}
```

Should be this:

```
if ((curcookie > result2) && (curcookie < result3)) {
    $(".div2").show();
}
```

Check out the fixed version here - **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rbhz7Lfj/1/)**